# Access denied on register form

Tags: 8, users, navigation

I wanted to edit my register menu link so I could show the registration link in the menu account only for anonymous user (not logged in users). But when I try to edit the register menu link the following error occurs:

> Access denied
>
> `Home >> Administration >> Structure >> Menus`
>
> You are not authorized to access this page.

The link I'm trying to access supossedly

> localhost/admin/structure/menu/item/8/edit?destination=/admin/structure/menu/manage/account

PS: I created a new registration form and in that one I could edit and show the the link in users menu only not logged in users but in this one I can't access even I have an admin role.

Log message:
[image: log message access denied]

Comment: When you say "created a new registration form" are you meaning that you are trying to replace the default registration form provided in the Drupal core by default?

Comment: Yes, I used the webform module to help me create a new one.

Comment: This is a core bug, nothing you're doing wrong. I suggest you create a bug report. I noticed this too, also with user/login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody told me an answer, I figure a way to bypass the error, creating other menu link and this time as I wanted when I was creating so I didn't need to edit.

It's not a permanent solution but it's a way to go through.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit to the permission page- /admin/people/permissions page and scroll down to check menu permissions for administrator and allow the checkbox to create and edit menus, check the checkbox for Administrator menus and menu items. It is checked by default, but in your case you can verify it.
Also I have seen your localhost link has a missing foldername, should be like this-
localhost/foldername/admin/structure/menu/item/8/edit?destination=/admin/structure/menu/manage/account

Comment: On the permissions page I already had checked and have all permissions for administrator checked.
As for the foldername thing I didn't quite understood what was the problem, I already have a folder in my pc for drupal "/home/user/public_html"

Comment: Drupal folders(sites/modules etc) are at the root(/home/user/public_html) or are under any specific folder(/home/user/public_html/foldername)?

Comment: My contrib/custom modules are here "/home/user/public_html/modules".
My core modules are here "/home/user/public_html/core/modules"

Comment: Please go through the same issue [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2492513), hope this will help you.

Comment: I didn't understood how to apply the patch. But yeah, that seems a good solution